# If $x$ is an arbitrary real number, prove that there is exactly one integer $n$ which satisfies $x$ $\le$ $n$ $<$ $x$ $+$ $1$.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

> If $x$ is an arbitrary real number, prove that there is exactly one integer $n$ which satisfies $x \le n < x + 1$.

I've come up with a proof myself, but I'd like you guys to critique it, because I'm not totally convinced that I'm being as rigorous as I could be for an analysis study context.

Let $A = \{ n \in \Bbb Z : n\ge x\}$.

Let $n$ be the smallest integer greater than $x$ **[Here's where I most doubt of the rigorousness of my proof. Am I allowed to summon this $n$ out of nowhere?]**. Since $n\in A$, $n \ge\inf A$. But, if $n >\inf A$ there is a non-integer real number $y$ such that $\inf A < y < n$, which is absurd, because if it was so $y$ would be a lower bound for $A$ greater than the greatest lower bound. Hence $n =\inf A$.

From the definition of infimum, we have $x \le \inf A$, since any element of $A$ is equal to or greater than $x$. There are, therefore, two possible cases:

i) If $x =\inf A \Rightarrow \inf A < x + 1 \Rightarrow n < x + 1$. Therefore $n$ is an integer which satisfies $x \le n < x + 1$.

ii) If $x < \inf A \Rightarrow x < n$. In this case, $0 < n - x < 1$, because $n$ is the smallest integer greater than $x$, which implies that $n < x + 1$. Therefore $n$ is an integer which satisfies $x \le n < x + 1$.

About the uniqueness of $n$:

If $m \in A \Rightarrow m \ge n$, because $n = \inf A$. But if $m > n \Rightarrow m \ge n + 1 \ge x + 1$, hence $m$ doesn't satisfy $x \le m < x + 1$. Therefore we conclude that $n$ is unique.

Comment: For the first paragraph, you should use the well-ordering principle: $A$ has a smallest element which we call $n$ (since $A$ is bounded below by construction and is non-empty by Archimedes). This reduces the argument as well. Also part (ii) needs more justification, but notice that $n-1$ is smaller than $n$ and therefore by inf properties, you will acquire what you want.

Answer (score 3):

If there were none, there would two *consecutive* integers (the smallest before $x$, the largest at least $x+1$) which differ by more than $1$.

If there were more than $1$, there would be two integers which differ by less than $1$.

Comment: I get your point, but isn't it more of a intuitive proof rather than a rigorous one?

Comment: For me it is a sketch (to be more or less developed, depending on whom  it is written for), but a proof written in ordinaty language can be perfectly rigourous.

Answer (score 3):

I'll use quite the same logic, but will try to be rigorous.
Let's first choose large enough $k \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $x'=x+k>0$ (this exists as $\mathbb{N}$ is unbounded.

Let, $$S = \{ m \in \mathbb{N} \mid m \geq x'\}$$
Now, as $S$ is a set of natural numbers, by well ordering property, it has a least number, say $n'$.
Now, $x'+1 \leq n' \implies x' \leq n'-1$. But, that's not possible, since $n'$ is the smallest element of $S$. Hence, $x'+1 > n'$.

Put $n=n'-k$. Clearly, this is the desired $n$.

The uniqueness part is obvious as $x \leq n,n' <x+1 \implies |n-n'|<1 \implies n=n'$ as both of them are integers.

EDIT : Some *really* dumb errors corrected after 3 long years thanks to @user0.

Comment: You mean to have _n_ replaced by _k_ in the last three sentences.  You also assume that _x_ is positive.

Comment: @user0 You're absolutely correct. IDK what I was thinking back then.

Answer (score 0):

let $x = [x]+\{x\}$, here $[x]$ is the maximum integer which less than $x$, so $0 \le \{x\} < 1$.

so we have $[x]+\{x\} \le n \le [x]+1+\{x\}$, let $y = n-[x]$, it is $\{x\} \le y \le 1+\{x\}$, just need to proof there is a integer $y$. but clearly, $y=1$ is the solution.

Comment: hmm, if the right is $<$, not $\le$, now, when $\{x\} > 0$, $y = 1$ is the solution. when $\{x\} = 0$, $y = 0$ is the solution.

Comment: Sure, but can you then prove rigorously that $x\mapsto [x]$ is well defined function? It's more or less but a variation of the original problem from OP.

Comment: I think with $[x]$, the existence based on Archimedes axiom, and the uniqueness is guaranteed by maximum.

Answer (score 0):

First suppose there are more than one integers (namely m > 1 integers) such that

> 1) $x \le n \le n+1 \le ... \le n+m-1 < x+1$.

Subtract x through the inequality 1):

> 2) $0 \le n-x \le n+1-x \le ... \le n+m-1-x < 1$.

This means $n+1-x < 1$. Subtract one: $n-x < 0$. This contradicts the first inequality in 2), hence there aren't more than one integers.

Second suppose there are zero integers such that:

> 3) $k < x < x+1 \le k+1$

where k is an integer. Now subtract k from 3):

> 4) $0 < x-k < x+1-k \le 1$

This means that $x+1-k \le 1$. Subtract one: $x-k \le 0$. However this contradicts 4), so there must be one integer.